# How to repartition the ds of DolphinDB's function mr?

Tags: mapreduce, distributed-computing, dolphindb

I have a partitioned table with two levels of partitions. The first level is time partition by days and the second level is HASH partition of stock codes. Now I want to process all stock data for multiple days with `mr` function, and repartition the data sources by stock ID. So I need to repartition the datasource. Any function can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DolphinDB's `repartitionDS` function:

```
ds = repartitionDS(query=<select DateTime,SecurityID from loadTable("dfs://SH_TSDB_snapshot_MultiColumn", "snapshot") where date(DateTime) in 2021.12.01 2021.12.06 2021.12.07, SecurityID in `600021`603659>, column=`SecurityID, partitionScheme=`a`b)
def disctcode(t){
    r1 = select distinct(date(DateTime))  as date from t
    r2 = select distinct(SecurityID)  as SecurityID from t
    return r1,r2
}

timer{
a1,a2=mr(ds, disctcode, ,)
b1 = unionAll(a1,0,0)
b2 = unionAll(a2,0,0)
}
```